how to increase precision when using the fpu library?
I'm not getting full floating point precision when using the fpu library. What am I doing wrong?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp,pgf,pgffor,pgfmath}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
Here are the (accurate) results using the fp package:
\def\temp{0,...,4}
\foreach \x [
  remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0.5)
] in \temp {
  \\Iiteration=\x; value=\lastx \FPeval\x{cos(\lastx)}
}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=float}

Here are the (inaccurate) results using pgf/fpu:
\def\temp{0,...,4}
\foreach \x [
  evaluate=\x as \fy using {cos(\lasty r)},
  remember=\fy as \lasty (initially 0.5)
] in \temp {\\Iteration=\x; value=$\lasty$
}
\end{document} 



The problem with pgfmath is that it converts the FPU results back to a length then a macro (\fy).  This is (probably) why the fpu package was written.

There is the pgfmath-xfp package which allows you to define pgfmath functions that internally use l3fp for their calculations (disclaimer: I'm the package author).
With that you get decent precision without changing too much of your pgfmath usage. Just note that cos in l3fp is taking the value in radian, unlike in pgfmath where it takes degrees (in l3fp there is cosd for a cosinus that accepts degrees as argument).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp,pgf,pgffor,pgfmath,pgfmath-xfp}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{l3cos}{1}{cos(#1)}
\begin{document}
Here are the (accurate) results using the fp package:
\def\temp{0,...,4}
\foreach \x [
  remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0.5)
] in \temp {
  \\Iiteration=\x; value=\lastx \FPeval\x{cos(\lastx)}
}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=float}

Here are the (inaccurate) results using pgf/fpu:
\def\temp{0,...,4}
\foreach \x [
  evaluate=\x as \fy using {l3cos(\lasty)},
  remember=\fy as \lasty (initially 0.5)
] in \temp {\\Iteration=\x; value=$\lasty$
}
\end{document}



Is there some way to just say "whenever available, use xfp definitions instead of pgfmath definitions in this document". Btw, I strongly agree cos should take a radians argument, but given the pgfmath decision against this, maybe name it cosr (or allow parameterization, as in pgfmath)?

@Alan well, apart from the definitions being incompatible sometimes (radian vs degree for instance) this would slow down your processing quite a bit. The approach used in that package is to parse the argument to the functions through pgfmath (with the fpu  locally activated and its output format set to sci), then do the calculations in l3fp, and pass the result back to pgfmath. And I'm kind of wary to replace all pgfmath functions for unforeseen side effects.

The fpu library of PGF has very limited accuracy.
I'd use expl3. The first mandatory argument is the recursion formula, where the current value is denoted by #1; the second argument is the number of iterations, the third argument is the initial value.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\printiterations}{ommm}
 {% #1 = optional prologue
  % #2 = recursion
  % #3 = number of iterations
  % #4 = initial value
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \group_begin:
  \cs_set:Nn \__alan_iterate:n {#2}
  \dim_set:Nn \parindent {0pt}
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1\par}
  \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#4}
  Iteration~0:~\fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp \par
  \int_step_inline:nn {#3}
   {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { \__alan_iterate:n { \l_tmpa_fp } }
    Iteration~##1:~\fp_use:N \l_tmpa_fp \par
   }
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printiterations{cos(#1)}{4}{0.5}

\printiterations[$x_{n+1}=e^{-x_n}$]{exp(-#1)}{12}{0.5}

\end{document}

The second example is the (approximate) solution of xex = 1, that is, W(1) (Lambert's function).


Thanks. I seem to have misread the fpu documentation, which I understood as claiming at least double-precision accuracy.

In OpTeX, we can use \expr macro. Its precision is about 16 decimal digits:
\mathinexpr
\def\p#1{Iteration: #1: \val \par}
\optdef\printiterations[]#1#2#3{% 
   % #1: recursion, #2: number of iterations, #3: initial value
   \medskip
   \the\opt\par
   \def\val{#3}\p0
   \fornum 1..#2 \do{\edef\val{\expr[16]{#1}}\p{##1}}
}

\printiterations{cos(\val)}{4}{0.5}

\printiterations[$x_{n+1}=e^{-x_n}$]{exp(-\val)}{12}{0.5}

\bye


If you're free to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, you may want to look into using Lua's plenty-accurate math library. No need to load any LaTeX packages...

\documentclass{article}
%% no need to load any packages...
\begin{document}
Here are the accurate results using Lua's \verb+math.cos+ function:

\noindent
\directlua{
  j=0.5
  for i=0,4 do
    tex.print ( "Iteration="..i.."; value="..j.."\\\\" )
    j=math.cos(j) % update 'j'
  end}

\end{document}

